# Godaddy api gives empty array as response when tested in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, godaddy-api

I am trying to hit the godaddy api for looking the list of domains with the expected search as below,
[Postman image edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIKZq.png)
it gives me an empty array as response. Please help, M i doing some wrong in hitting this?

Answer (score 0):

Status is 200 so your authentication was not a problem.
Check your params again to make sure you are passing them correctly. I see a param: `marker: clothing'` that might have a missing quote.

Comment: I have changed this missing quote, but the issue still remain same. plz help

Comment: can you send me a screenshot updated postman API call?

Comment: i updated the ques. plz check now